# Substract SVG HSLA colours on intersection

Tags: svg, heatmap, hsl

I'm trying to make a kind of "heatmap". When two svg elements with color and opacity intersect, they get darker or unexpected colour on the intersection, i would like to substract those colours in HSLA scale so for example if i had a green ellipse and a yellow ellipse, the intersection would probably be orange or close to red, think of it as a kind of heatmap that when two colours intersect, they get hotter.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
    <ellipse cx="200" cy="200" rx="100" ry="100" id="ellipse1" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    <ellipse cx="250" cy="200" rx="100" ry="100" id="ellipse2" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: perhaps experiment with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode perhaps one of the modes is suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you need a custom color for the fill I would use `clipPath`. You can reuse the first shape clipped by the second shape.

Please observe that both shapes are in the `<defs>` with no `fill` or `oppacity`. You then use those shapes with an `<use>` element with the desired `fill`.

You also use one of those shapes to create the `<clipPath>`.

Finally you are giving the clipped path the desired fill, oppacity etc...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
  <defs>
    <ellipse cx="200" cy="200" rx="100" ry="100" id="ellipse1" />
    <ellipse cx="250" cy="200" rx="100" ry="100" id="ellipse2" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <use xlink:href="#ellipse2" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#ellipse1" fill="yellow" fill-opacity="0.5" />
  <use xlink:href="#ellipse2" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5" />
  <use xlink:href="#ellipse1" clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="red" />
</svg>
```